# App engine Flexible Crashing due to threading or due to saving files in /tmp?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, task

in my flask application i want to run a small task multiple times until End of imput from list,for this i have used queues as well as threading since app engine doesn't allow more than 8 threads at a time,the function saves a file to the /tmp directory and deletes all created the files as soon as it finishes processing
the function takes object as argument and have zero clue how i would go about doing it using google cloud tasks
app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
instance_class: F2
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7
env_variables:
  CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME: "my username"
  CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
  CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME: "db"
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: "conn"
entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :8080 main:app --log-level=DEBUG --timeout=600
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 8
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances:
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

main.py

```
from queue import Queue

jobs = Queue()


def heavy_func(object, text_file, mp3_file):
    """do some small task downloads from object.url and rename mp3 file"""

    return """saved the file in /tmp directory"""


def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = q.get()
        q.task_done()


"""this is the main funtion"""


def some_route():
    for i in string_list:
        jobs.put(heavy_func(object, text_file, mp3_file))
    for i in range(3):
        worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs,))
        worker.start()
    print("waiting for queue to complete", jobs.qsize(), "tasks")
    jobs.join()
    print("all done")
```

this is what i have i tried,this still crashed app engine flex

Comment: 1) What error do you actually get? 2) Is this working on your dev env? 3) Do you really need an SQL DB (don't see where it's being used in your code and it's a possible failure point 4) Why do you have to save the data in /tmp

Answer (score 0):

had to use worker class gevent to fix this issue and reduce number of workers to just 2 in my gunicorn.conf.py file

```
workers = 2
worker_class = "gevent"
```